# How would I optimize a nested for loop with linq

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, linq-to-entities

How would i write this with linq?

```
foreach (var to in allCurrentTradeObjects)
{
    foreach (var ro in theseWantMe)
    {
        if (ro.Type != to.Type
                || ro.MaxRent < to.Rent
                || ro.MinRooms > to.Rooms
                || ro.MinSquareMeters > to.SquareMeters
                || ro.MaxPrice < to.Price
                || ro.MinFloors > to.Floors
                || ro.TradeObjectId == to.TradeObjectId
                || ro.TradeObjectId == myTradeObject.TradeObjectId)
        {
            continue;
        }
        RatingListTriangleModel rlt = new RatingListTriangleModel
        {
            To1Id = myTradeObject.TradeObjectId,
            To2Id = to.TradeObjectId,
            To3Id = ro.TradeObjectId,
            T1OnT2Rating = 0,
            T2OnT3Rating = 0,
            T3OnT1Rating = 0,
            TotalRating = 0
        };

        //_context.RatingListTriangle.Add(rlt);
        this.InsertOrUpdate(rlt);

    }
}
this.Save();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = from to in allCurrentTradeObjects
            from ro in theseWantMe
            where ro.Type == to.Type &&
                  ro.MaxRent >= to.Rent &&
                  ro.MinRooms <= to.Rooms &&
                  ro.MinSquareMeters <= to.SquareMeters &&
                  ro.MaxPrice >= to.Price &&
                  ro.MinFloors <= to.Floors &&
                  ro.TradeObjectId != to.TradeObjectId &&
                  ro.TradeObjectId != myTradeObject.TradeObjectId
            select new RatingListTriangleModel
            {
                To1Id = myTradeObject.TradeObjectId,
                To2Id = to.TradeObjectId,
                To3Id = ro.TradeObjectId,
                T1OnT2Rating = 0,
                T2OnT3Rating = 0,
                T3OnT1Rating = 0,
                TotalRating = 0
            };

foreach(var rlt in query)
   this.InsertOrUpdate(rlt);

this.Save();
```

Comment: Let's here it for linq. I mean that's ways better. :( :( :( +1 anyway

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I think this is a optimization for readability..

Comment: Um, readability to me would be an overload on the constructor, and some sort of comparator on ro and to. Though reversing the logic and getting rid of that continue statement made the code 100% more readable straight off. Took me five minutes to even notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Start by converting the skeleton of the nested loops to LINQ:

```
 var rtls = allCurrentTradeObjects
     .SelectMany(to => theseWantMe.Select(ro => new {to, ro}));
```

This gives you a list of pairs `{to, ro}`. Now add filtering by inverting the `continue` condition:

```
 var rtls = allCurrentTradeObjects
     .SelectMany(to => theseWantMe.Select(ro => new {to, ro}));
     .Where(p => p.ro.Type == p.to.Typpe && p.ro.MaxRent >= p.to.Rent && ...)
```

Finally, add a `Select` to call `new:

```
 var rtls = allCurrentTradeObjects
     .SelectMany(to => theseWantMe.Select(ro => new {to, ro}));
     .Where(p => p.ro.Type == p.to.Typpe && p.ro.MaxRent >= p.to.Rent && ...)
    .Select(p => new RatingListTriangleModel {
        To1Id = myTradeObject.TradeObjectId,
        To2Id = p.to.TradeObjectId,
        To3Id = p.ro.TradeObjectId,
        ...
    });
```

With `rtls` list in hand, you can call `InsertOrUpdate` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the method syntax.

```
allCurrentTradeObjects.Select (
            to => to.theseWantMe.Where ( ro => !(ro.Type != to.Type 
                || ro.MaxRent < to.Rent
                || ro.MinRooms > to.Rooms
                || ro.MinSquareMeters > to.SquareMeters
                || ro.MaxPrice < to.Price
                || ro.MinFloors > to.Floors
                || ro.TradeObjectId == to.TradeObjectId
                || ro.TradeObjectId == myTradeObject.TradeObjectId))
               .Select({
                             var rlt =  new RatingListTriangleModel
                              {
                                 To1Id = myTradeObject.TradeObjectId,
                                 To2Id = to.TradeObjectId,
                                 To3Id = ro.TradeObjectId,
                                 T1OnT2Rating = 0,
                                 T2OnT3Rating = 0,
                                 T3OnT1Rating = 0,
                                TotalRating = 0
                            };
                           this.InsertOrUpdate(rlt);
                           return rlt;
                         } ).ToArray();
 this.Save();
```

Comment: Can't find where `theseWantMe` collection in your query. Who upvoted this..

Comment: I missed it at first glance. Now corrected.

Comment: `theseWantMe` is not a property of `ro`..

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers here advocating SelectMany (or double from).  These are "optimize for readability" answers in that they do not change the N*M nested loop performance of this operation.

You shouldn't use that approach if both collections are large.  Instead, you should take advantage of the well defined relationship between your two collections, and the hashing in Enumerable.Join to reduce the operation to N+M.

```
var myTradeObject = GetThatOneObject();

IEnumerable<RatingListTriangleModel> query =
  from to in allCurrentTradeObjects
 //pre-emptively filter to the interesting objects in the first collection
  where to.TradeObjectId == myTradeObject.TradeObjectId
 //take advantage of hashing in Enumerable.Join - theseWantMe is enumerated once
  join ro in theseWantMe
    on to.Type equals ro.Type
 //remaining matching criteria
  where to.Rent <= ro.MaxRent   //rent is lower than max
    && ro.MinRooms <= to.Rooms   //rooms are higher than min
    && ro.MinSquareMeters <= to.SquareMeters  //area is higher than min
    && to.Price <= ro.MaxPrice     //price is lower than max
    && ro.MinFloors <= to.Floors   // floors are higher than min
    && to.TradeObjectId != ro.TradeObjectId //not same trade object
  select CreateRatingListTriangleModel(myTradeObject, to, ro);

foreach(RatingListTriangleModel row in query)
{
  this.InsertOrUpdate(row);
}
this.Save();
```

Comment: Thanks David, I tried it but I'm cant figure out why I'm not getting any results in my query using this?

Answer (score 0):

To increase readability I would start by refactoring the complicated condition and move it to a neat little function (It can also be a method of the object)

```
private bool IsMatchingTradeObject (TradeObject to, SomeOtherObject ro, int TradeObjectId)
{
  return ro.Type == to.Type &&
                  ro.MaxRent >= to.Rent &&
                  ro.MinRooms <= to.Rooms &&
                  ro.MinSquareMeters <= to.SquareMeters &&
                  ro.MaxPrice >= to.Price &&
                  ro.MinFloors <= to.Floors &&
                  ro.TradeObjectId != to.TradeObjectId &&
                  ro.TradeObjectId != TradeObjectId;
}
```

Second I would do the same with the creation and initialization of the `RatingListTriangleModel`, i.e. move it to a small method and give it a meaningful name.

```
private RatingListTriangleModel CreateModel(TradeObject to, SomeOtherObject ro, int TradeObjectId)
{
  return new RatingListTriangleModel
    {
        To1Id = myTradeObject.TradeObjectId,
        To2Id = to.TradeObjectId,
        To3Id = ro.TradeObjectId,
        T1OnT2Rating = 0,
        T2OnT3Rating = 0,
        T3OnT1Rating = 0,
        TotalRating = 0
    };
```

The remaining code is much easier to read

```
   foreach (var to in allCurrentTradeObjects)
     foreach (var ro in theseWantMe)
       if (IsMatchingTradeObject(to, ro, myTradeObject.TradeObjectId))
         this.InsertOrUpdate(CreateModel(to, ro, myTradeObject.TradeObjectId));

this.Save();
```

Converting this to LINQ is easy:

```
allCurrentTradeObjects.Select (
  to => to.Where ( 
    ro => IsMatchingTradeObject (to, ro, myTradeObject.TradeObjectId)
    )
  ).Select(
     {
       this.InsertOrUpdate(CreateModel(to, ro, myTradeObject.TradeObjectId));
       return null;
     } 
  );
 this.Save();
```

However, the foreach-loops seem easier to read.